# How to make jQuery select onchange

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want make forgot password page. The page can use email or sms, i want make select button for choose another one. Can help me?

This is my view

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 col-xxs">
                <label class="control-label">Confirm Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-7 col-xxs">
                <input placeholder="Email address." class="form-control" type="text" name="re_email" value="<?php echo input_data('re_email'); ?>">
                    <?php echo form_error('re_email'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" 
                 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-4
                 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8
                 ">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's your mean about `make select button for choose another one`?

Comment: i just want select onchange. Just select one email or sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways how you can achieve that. I'm presenting you the first one came to my mind. Also, it depends how do you want your UX to work.

```
<div class="form-group hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 col-xxs">
            <label class="control-label">Select email or sms</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-7 col-xxs">
            <select  class="form-control my-select" name="re_email">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="email">Email</option>
                <option value="sms">SMS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group hidden" id="email-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 col-xxs">
            <label class="control-label">Confirm Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-7 col-xxs">
            <input placeholder="Email address." class="form-control" type="text" name="re_email" value="<?php echo input_data('re_email'); ?>">
                <?php echo form_error('re_email'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
 <div class="form-group hidden" id="sms-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" 
             col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-4
             col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8
             ">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden{display: none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '.my-select', function() {
            var selection = $(this).val();
            $('input[type=text]').addClass('hidden');
            $('#' + selection + '-input').removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });

</script>
```

First, you need a select input with your 2 options. Then give your email and sms inputs hidden class so they don't show until user selects option (dont forget the style element that actually applies hidden class). Then jQuery.....get the value of the select input and use it to access either email or sms input by id attribute. With jquery you add hidden class first to all text inputs (email and sms) to hide them and then you only show the one user selected.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: i try u code select one is working but i select email he just display Confirm Email Address.

Answer (score 0):

**You can take two radio button to select By Email Id or SMS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('input[type=radio][name=forgotpass]').change(function()
    {
      if (this.value == 'email') 
      {
        do something
      }
      else if (this.value == 'sms') 
      {
        do something
      }
    });
});
```